# Scala loop illegal start of simple pattern

Tags: scala

I have the following loop in Scala:

```
for(var i <- 1 to q) {
  val Array(a, p, q) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
  println(a ^ xs(findXorFromRoot(x, rev_binary_encoding(a).reverse, p, q)))
}
```

However, on the first line, I get:

```
error: illegal start of simple pattern
```

Why is that?

Is this not a valid loop declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `var` reserved word does not have any sense here.  This `for` loop is translated into a `foreach` statement, it is equivalent to:

```
(1 to q) foreach { i =>
    val Array(a, p, q) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
    println(a ^ xs(findXorFromRoot(x, rev_binary_encoding(a).reverse,  p, q)))
}
```

So you should change your code to:

```
for(i <- 1 to q) {
    val Array(a, p, q) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
    println(a ^ xs(findXorFromRoot(x, rev_binary_encoding(a).reverse, p, q)))
}
```